# Arrow under navigation bars

Tags: html, css

I think this is a very basic problem but I can't seem to understand how it is done.

Consider this navigation bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgsp4.jpg

How do you put that arrow beneath the Artists Profile?

Comment: You need to reword the question, habe you tried any code?  Also, this is very basic css, try googling css sprites, and background images.

Comment: Yeah my bad for being lazy. Now that I've researched a little, it's actually very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below example:

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/f7d7K/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

​

CSS

```
.active {
       background:#ccc url(path/to/image/marker.png) center bottom no-repeat; 
}
```

Jquery

```
$("ul li a").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be the background-image of that particular menu tab.
When it has, say, `class='active'`, that particular tab will have that background image, otherwise, it'll be the default, plain one.

Maybe something like this:

```
.menutabs {
background: url(something.jpg);
}

.menutabs .active {
background: url(something_with_arrow.jpg);
}
```

To add class 'active' (or any other name), you have to do that via jQuery.
Though it'd be best to show us what you have.

Cheers!